# Pandas Collapse and Stack Multi-level columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to break down multi level columns and have them as a column value.

Original data input (excel):

[image]

As read in dataframe:

```
  Company Name Company code 2017-01-01 00:00:00 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5 2017-02-01 00:00:00 Unnamed: 7 Unnamed: 8 Unnamed: 9 2017-03-01 00:00:00 Unnamed: 11 Unnamed: 12 Unnamed: 13
0          NaN          NaN           Product A  Product B  Product C  Product D           Product A  Product B  Product C  Product D           Product A   Product B   Product C   Product D
1    Company A         #123                   1          5          3          5                   0          2          3          4                   0           1           2           3
2    Company B         #124                 600        208         30         20                 600        213         30         15                 600         232          30          12
3    Company C         #125                 520        112         47         15                 520        110         47         10                 520         111          47          15
4    Company D         #126                 420        165        120         31                 420        195        120         30                 420         182         120          58
```

Intended data frame:

[image]

I have tried `stack()` and `unstack()` and also swap level, but I couldn't get the dates column to 'drop as row'. Looks like the merged cells in excels will produce `NaN` as in the dataframes - and if its the columns that is merged, I will have a unnamed column. How do I work around it? Am I missing something really simple here?

Answer (score 0):

Using `stack`

```
df.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=1)
```